# Getting "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'" while using pytesseract

Tags: python, flask, python-tesseract

Getting TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple' using pytesseract in flask

```
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        imagefile = request.files['img'].read()
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imagefile))
        #image.show()
        print(type(image))
        text = (pytesseract.image_to_string(image,'eng+kan'))
        #rint(imagefile.read())
        #print(type(imagefile))
        print(text)
    return render_template('predict.html')
```

Comment: Full traceback would be useful information

Comment: @ex4 thanks but I figured out a way to make it work just had to apply some preprocessing.

Comment: @White_Wolf: How exactly did you apply this preprocessing?
It would help me too. I'm facing this same issue.